# Is there a place for Android Web Stores or Web Apps for Android?

Tags: discussion

This doesn't quite fit on Web Applications.se, Software Recommendations.se or Android.se.

Would a question like this be acceptable for meta?

Right now I have an example store pinned under starred comments under chat.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What doesn't quite fit?  A question like what?

Comment: @Chenmunka check example stores under chat